# MacBook Pro connected to WiFi hotspot but offline

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wifi, tethering

I've recently bought a 4G data plan on my phone with the intention to connect my MacBook to it via hotspot tethering. It is connecting fine to the hotspot but, it's offline. I've connected other devices and another MacBook Pro to the connection and all worked fine. I tried to renew my DHCP lease, turn my phone, my hotspot and my computer on/off again, and deleting the connection and reconnecting but nothing worked. I checked to see if i can ping on terminal but that timed out so I'm definitely offline.

Comment: Which macOS do you have on your MacBook?

Comment: You said you tried to renew your DHCP lease - what IP address did you get?  How is DHCP configured on your MacBook (the one that's offline)?  How many devices do you have connected to your hotspot?  What's the limit?